# Multi level map to Json structure in java

Tags: java, json, collections, multi-level

I am trying to convert the multi level map into Json where level of the map can be any. For example

I have map like

```
    Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
    m.put("data.test[1].tool",6);
    m.put("data.test[1].sets",8);
    m.put("data.test[2].tool",9);
    m.put("data.test[2].sets",12);
    
    m.put("data.tem[1].use[1]",6);
    m.put("data.tem[1].use[2]",9);
    
    m.put("data.tut.seh",6)
```

I want to convert this to

```
{
  "data": {
    "test": [
      {
        "tool": 6,
        "sets": 8
      },
      {
        "tool": 9,
        "sets": 12
      }
    ],
    "tem": [
      {
        "use": [
          6,
          9
        ]
      }
    ],
    "tut": {
      "seh": 6
    }
  }
}
```

Something like the proper json which maintain the order as well like value 6 and 8 belong to the first index of test so they should come at first and the second array should come with 9 and 12 inside test array. As this json will be used later to retrieve the exact value on the basis of index.

If some one can give me some idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you `put`ting JSONPaths into the map instead of constructing the map to represent the object structure (i.e., have a "multilevel"-map)?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Do not use "data.test[1].tool" as key. Instead, parse this string and construct to map.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am actually not putting these values into the Map. Here I was just creating the map to show how the values will look like. The map which such values I am getting from some other function which I could not have control to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Bean class to store the data and get it from there,
I was tried like there, It may help you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
public static  void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
   /* your code
    Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
    m.put("data.test[1].tool",6);
    m.put("data.test[1].sets",8);
    m.put("data.test[2].tool",9);
    m.put("data.test[2].sets",12);

    m.put("data.tem[1].use[1]",6);
    m.put("data.tem[1].use[2]",9);

    m.put("data.tut.seh",6);

    System.out.println(m);
   */

    Map m1 = new LinkedHashMap();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("listItem1");
    m1.put(new BeanToMap("withList",list),"mapValueWithList");
    m1.put(new BeanToMap("test"),"test");

    System.out.println(m1);



   }


}
```

Bean class is :

```
   import java.util.*;
   public class BeanToMap {
   private String name;
   private List<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BeanToMap(String name, List<String> cars) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public BeanToMap(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<String> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
  }
```

you can set all the values to string then you can use

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
```